# Jquery - why doesn't counter count correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when I load a page it shows the correct values of counter for all categories, but when I type some part in the search field it miscounts it. where did i make a mistake?
i have some divs with span elements which have got the attribute `data-category`

and i have other divs where i got counter and i want to display value of number divs that equal `data-category`

here is one of elements div:

```
<div class="box col-md-12 app_box"  id="Acrobat Reader 10">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 0; margin-top:0">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <h3>Acrobat Reader 10</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <h3><small>Adobe Systems</small></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0px">                
                <span class="label label-primary" data-category="-1" style="display:none"></span>
                                    <span class="label label-primary" data-category="1">
                                            New1
                                        </span>
                                    <span class="label label-primary" data-category="4">
                                            new4
                                        </span>
                            </div>
            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top:0">
                                    <p>Adobe® Reader® software is the free global standard for reliably viewing, printing, and commenting on PDF documents</p>
                            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it contains 2 span elements with `data-category` equal `1` and `4`
and here is how looks like my counter div

```
    <div id="category_list" class="list-group">
        <a href="#" data-category="-1" class="list-group-item active">
            <span class="badge"></span>All applications</a>
                <a href="#" data-category="1" class="list-group-item">
            <span class="badge"></span>
                        New1
                    </a>          
                <a href="#" data-category="2" class="list-group-item">
            <span class="badge"></span>
                        new2
                    </a>          
                <a href="#" data-category="3" class="list-group-item">
            <span class="badge"></span>
                        new3
                    </a>          
                <a href="#" data-category="4" class="list-group-item">
            <span class="badge"></span>
                        new4
                    </a>          

    </div>
```

where in span elements i want to display visible div number which contains `data-category` as said

here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    count();

    $('#appName').changed(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        search();
        count();
    });

    $("#category_list a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#category_list a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        search();
    });

    function search() {
        var category = $("#category_list a.active").attr('data-category');
        var value = $('#appName').val();
        $('.app_box').each(function() {
            var box = $(this);
            if (box.find("[data-category='" + category + "']").length > 0) {
                if (box.find('h3').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                    box.fadeIn();
                }
                else
                    box.fadeOut();
            }
            else {
                box.fadeOut();
            }
        });
    }
    function count() {
        $('#category_list .badge').each(function() {
            var category = $(this).parent().attr('data-category');
            var counter = 0;
            $('.app_box').each(function() {
                var box = $(this);
                if (box.find("[data-category='" + category + "']").length > 0) {
                    if (box.is(':visible')) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            });
            $(this).text(counter);
        });
    }
});
```

there is also an input field where i search applications as you can see in my js

```
<div class="col-lg-4 pull-right" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="appName" placeholder="Search for an app..." type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="buttonFind" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
</div>
```

Comment: My guess is the animation is still running so :visible still counts them since they are not fully hidden.

Comment: jquery doesnt have changed(), did you mean change()?

Comment: i added http://azoffdesign.com/changed When i use show/hide its count correctly so how can i fix it to invoke after all are fadeout fadein done ?

Comment: jquery fadeOut()/fadeIn() takes a callback. Or you can also use $.Deferred()

Comment: `search().done(function() {
            count();
        });` if i do like this in my `$('#appName').changed` it count all the time also when i display em for diffrent categories

Comment: sorry it was cous i tried `.fadeOut('fast', count);` before and i forgot to change it. and the `search().done(function() { count(); });` doesnt work

Comment: if you are using deferred, then you dont need to use a callback

Comment: can you give me an example cous im now pretty lost what to do

Comment: You want count() to fire after search()?

Comment: yes, cous it count before fadeout fadein are done and return wrong value